# Why is the background of the image not colored even when other set commands are working?

Tags: java, jpanel

Why isn't the background of this image showing up red even when all the other set commands work?

```
JPanel jp =new JPanel();
JLabel jl =new JLabel();
public Trial1()
{
    jp.setOpaque(false);
    jp.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);

    setTitle("name");
    setVisible(true);
    setSize(600,600);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setResizable(false);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


//finding and adding image      

    jl.setIcon(new ImageIcon("location"));
    jp.add(jl);
    add(jp);
    validate();
```

Comment: Perhaps your JPanel needs to be transparent? Based off [this user Stefan](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10148421/jpanel-setbackgroundcolor-black-does-nothing)

Answer (score 0):

Your JFrame's content pane is covered by the jp JPanel. Set it non-opaque:

```
jp.setOpaque(false);
```

Comment: i just entered that into the program and it does not produce an error but it does not change.

Comment: how would i go about that? i made the changes suggested and it is not colored